# Understanding Hostname of Containers in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I am trying to understand a [`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/confluentinc/docker-images/blob/master/examples/fullstack/docker-compose.yml) (also shown at the bottom of this post).

**Question:** `confluent:2181` is used the following line

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "confluent:2181"
```

How was this `confluent` hostname defined? If I understand hostnames in Docker correctly, the only container hostnames are `zookeeper`, `kafka`, `rest-proxy` and `schema-registry`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: confluent/zookeeper
        ports:
        - "2181:2181"
        environment:
        zk_id: "1"
        network_mode: "host"
    kafka:
        image: confluent/kafka
        depends_on:
        - zookeeper
        ports:
        - "9092:9092"
        environment:
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "confluent:2181"
        network_mode: "host"
    rest-proxy:
        image: confluent/rest-proxy
        depends_on:
        - zookeeper
        - kafka
        - schema-registry
        ports:
        - "8082:8082"
        environment:
        RP_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "confluent:2181"
        RP_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://confluent:8081"
        network_mode: "host"
    schema-registry:
        image: confluent/schema-registry
        depends_on:
        - kafka
        - zookeeper
        ports:
        - "8081:8081"
        environment:
        SR_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: "confluent:2181"
        network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. According to the `docker-compose.yml` the services being defined will provide DNS resolution only for `zookeeper`, `kafka`, `rest-proxy` and `schema-registry`, and not `confluent`.

However if you [take a look at the documenttion from confluentinc](https://github.com/confluentinc/docker-images#local-host-entries) they require you to modify your hosts file in your host machine:

> Edit your hosts file and add a host entry for the docker machine.
>
> 192.168.99.100  confluent

That's why you can use `confluent` and get name resolution. It doesn't have anything to do with docker or compose.

P.S: Beware that you're using deprecated images [according to their documentation](https://github.com/confluentinc/docker-images#confluent-stream-data-platform-on-docker-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

According to the [README](https://github.com/confluentinc/docker-images#docker-compose), you were supposed to run confluent firstly.